# Cannot find `@microsoft/office-js` under `node_modules`

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, office-js

My node version is `node/14.21.3`. I would like to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js in the project to avoid the `Office.js has not fully loaded` error when using CDN. I tried to start a reactjs project from the beginning by `create-react-app try`, and then `yarn add @microsoft/office-js` inside `try`. But there was still no `@microsoft/office-js` folder. Here is the current `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "try",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/office-js": "^1.1.88",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on a Mac, and it is there:

[image]

Command line confirms: `ls -la node_modules/@micro*` (if your terminal does not support bash-completion, then you need to enter it with the asterisk "*" to list all partials)

If you are on another platform, try and confirm using command line, file explorer, or IDE.

The [NPM docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js#use-the-npm-package) also lists:

> Installing the NPM package locally creates a set of static Office.js files in the node_modules@microsoft\office-js\dist folder of the directory where you ran the npm install command.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have that folder. I also tried to compile my `package.json` in an empty project. The generated `node_modules` did not have the `@microsoft` folder.

Comment: Can you give more info on your OS?

 - I know it shows in your package.json, but does NPM have reference to it? `npm list`
 - did you try in list it outside of your IDE, like file explorer/finder?
 - you can also try removing all node_modules and running a fresh install: `rm -rf node_modules && yarn`
 - clearing cache: `yarn cache clean && yarn`
 - As a last resort, you can manually download the package from npm and place it in your node_modules folder.

Comment: the OS is macOS Ventura Version 13.4.1 (c)

Comment: In `npm list` in a console, I can see `@microsoft/office-js@1.1.88`.

Comment: When I typed `ls node_modules/@micro` and the TAB key, it did not propose `ls node_modules/@microsoft`, so I though there was no `node_modules/@microsoft`. But I could well type `ls node_modules/@microsoft` where there is `office-js`.

Comment: Glad to hear you "found" it!

Comment: @SoftTimur - I added an explanation to the command "ls -la node_modules/@micro*" above. The "*" will help you search for partials, and therefore you do not have to rely on tab completion.

Answer (score -2):

Gernally speaking there is a reason why node_modules is hidden - Its' folder organization should be an implementation detail. If you need to check a version perhaps `yarn list --pattern <package_name>` will do. Package managers might organize package differently depending on the package manager and the version (links, vendors etc.). If you need to look at the code of the package I'd recommend searching by file name, or by entering source code. Then after you found a folder of the package, it will be easy to access the folder as well.

Comment: "yarn add",  "npm install" installs within node_modules. The OP asked why they cannot see the folder, despite the stated workflow. Conceptually why it should/should not be there does not answer their question, and the debug tip provided was already mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: @DavidP AFAIK by policy stackoverflow is meant for answering practical questions. The scope is - how to solve a specific problem.